# Is there an "Always synchronize tree to current document" option with any file tree explorers plugins in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have tried Explorer and LightExplorer, but both require me to click a super small button or right click -> "Synchronize tree to current document" to go to the current folder. I am wondering if there is another plugin or a setting I missed to auto synchronize the tree to the currently active document.